# Animate cell height change without fade

Tags: ios, uitableview

The following is called as I'm about to change a cell's height...

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

This is a basic animation that makes the cell either drop down, when its getting taller, or pull up, when getting shorter.

This is the effect I want except its adding in a fade effect too, which I don't want.

If I set the animation type to 'None' then it works correctly except now the cell isn't clipped (even with `clipsToBounds` selected) and its a little glitchy.

The other effects do strange things, I just want the cell to go up or down but without the fade. Is this possible?

Comment: you can animate the height change of the UITableView by setting the return funciton of heightForRowAtIndexPath to a instance variable and then setting this height value to something different using begin and end update calls on the tableview. This is all the hint I'm willing to give you because even doing this will turn into a nightmare for you. Animating changes in row height is a very stupid messy operation and I'd advise against it at all costs. But the idea is that you intercept the events in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and then do the height changes there, using beginUpdates and endUpdates

Comment: How can such a simple process get messy?

Comment: Hey! @IanWarburton did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JEL I can't remember, sorry.

Comment: @IanWarburton no worries, thank you